# jenkins pipeline script close() getting called without executing Closure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The following Jenkins pipeline script does not execute the code in the Closure.

```
class MyClass implements Closeable, Serializable {
    private final script

    MyClass(final script) {
        this.script = script
        this.script.echo "In MyClass()"
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        this.script.echo "In MyClass.close()"
    }
}

def sdk = new MyClass(this).withCloseable {
    println "In Closure ..."
}

println "Done"
```

```
This is the output:
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
In MyClass()
[Pipeline] echo
In MyClass.close()
[Pipeline] echo
Done
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Note that there is no "InClosure ..." string.
I had to approve the signature: method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object in order to run the above script.

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

I believe that the groovy version included with your Jenkins install does not support `.withCloseable`. Specifically, note that many Jenkins installs only have groovy version 1.8.9. Groovy didn't add the automatic `withCloseable` stuff until version 2, I think.

Longer:

You should not have approved the signature `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object`. Go and unapprove it, because it's not doing you any good, will potentially hide other errors/make them harder to track down, and is a security hole if you have non-admin developers submitting jobs to your Jenkins instance.

The interaction of groovy and Jenkins has an annoying little UI failure: if you try to invoke a method on an object that does not have that method, and the object's class is written in Groovy, you'll get a "Scripts not permitted to use method" error referring to `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object`. Not a `NoSuchMethodException`, not a helpful message about a bad method name, but a security error.

If you get that error message **specifically referring to `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod`**, it usually means "you have invoked a method that doesn't exist". In this case, I believe it was because the `groovy` installed on your Jenkins instance is too old and doesn't automatically add `withCloseable` to classes that implement `Closeable`.